# GAS - Basic Script

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I'm trying to do a simple script to transfer the entire line to "Sheet2" every time that the word "Correct" is typed on the 5th Column of the Sheet1.

What is wrong with the code below? Its doesnt works. And, sometimes, the following error message appears:

```
ReferenceError: "value" is undefined. (line 2, file "Resize")
```

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.value != "Correct" || e.range.columnStart != 5) return;
  dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
e.range.offset(0,-5,1,e.source.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn()).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,e.source.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn())); }
```

If this could help, I have the same function on VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Column <> 5 Then Exit Sub
 If Target.Value <> "Correct" Then Exit Sub
 Dim LR As Long
  With Sheets("Sheets2")
   LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   .Cells(LR + 1, 1).Resize(, 4).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Resize(, 4).Value
  End With
Rows(Target.Row).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: *What is wrong with the code below?* Provide [mcve]: provide error messages  and explain what happens

Comment: If you try to run it from editor, it'll throw that error. But it should work, if you edit or change column 5 to "Correct"

Answer (score 2):

### The problem is your offset

If `e.range.columnStart` is 5, then `e.range.offset(0,-5)` would be column 0, which is obviously not possible.